# Model List returning as null from view to controller ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble with a list within my model returning as null even tho in the view it clearly has some value.

I had trouble trying to add objects to my model's list, someone helped me and my problem was half solved. This is the code I came up with after the help

My view:

```
@model ActivityForm

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Activity Details";
}

<section class="my-sm-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
            <h1 class="h-02 flex-grow-1">Activity Details</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
                    <h1 class="h-04 flex-grow-1">Form</h1>
                </div>
                <form id="form" class="row g-3 w-90" asp-action="Create">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label asp-for="Description" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>
                            model.Description)</label>
                        <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label asp-for="StartDate" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>
                            model.StartDate)</label>
                        <input asp-for="StartDate" type="date" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)">
                        <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label asp-for="EndDate" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)</label>
                        <input asp-for="EndDate" type="date" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)">
                        <span asp-validation-for="EndDate" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-6">
                        <label asp-for="Points" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Points)</label>
                        <input asp-for="Points" type="number" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Points)">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Points" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 d-grid gap-2">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#add-award">Add award</a>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                    data-bs-target="#cancel-activity">Cancel</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                    data-bs-target="#post-activity">Post Activity</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal" id="add-award" tabindex="-1">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                            <div class="modal-content br-20 pd-20">
                                <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title h-04 text-prim-color">Award details</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row g-3">
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="row g-3">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <label asp-for="Award.Name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                                                <input asp-for="Award.Name" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                    id="award-name">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <label asp-for="Award.Description" for="inputAddress"
                                                    class="form-label">Description</label>
                                                <textarea asp-for="Award.Description" class="form-control"
                                                    id="award-description" rows="5"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100"
                                            data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <input class="btn btn-primary w-100" type="submit" value="Confirm"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
                    <h1 class="h-04 flex-grow-1">Awards</h1>
                </div>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Award name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (Model.Awards != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model.Awards)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                                    <td>@item.Description</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Remove</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Method in controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ActivityForm data)
        {
            var award = data.Award;

            if (award.Name != null && award.Description != null)
            {
                if (data.Awards == null) data.Awards = new List<AwardForm>();

                data.Awards.Add(new AwardForm { Name = award.Name, Description = award.Description });

                data.Award.Name = "";
                data.Award.Description = "";

                return View(data);
            }


            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(data);
            }

            string userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            await service.NewActivityAsync(data, userId);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Model

```
    public class ActivityForm
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public int Points { get; set; }

        public AwardForm Award { get; set; }

        public List<AwardForm> Awards { get; set; }
    }
```

Everything was now working as intended but I had one more issue left. When I try to add another Award to the list, the list is returned to the controller method as null.

I'm not really sure if the issue is related to binding, I have noticed that every other value is bound and is returning the expected value except the list which is not bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `foreach` loop to:

```
<tbody>
    @if (Model.Awards != null)
    {
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Awards.Count; i++)
        {
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Awards[i].Name" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Awards[i].Description" />
            <tr>            
                <td>@Model.Awards[i].Name</td>
                <td>@Model.Awards[i].Description</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Remove</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

This has same effect to what [@Victor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6630084/victor) suggested but using input tag helper instead of html helper.

Documentation for binding model to a collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#collections-1

Also your form should wrap around both **Form** and **Awards** sections:

```
<form id="form" class="row g-3 w-90" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
            <h1 class="h-04 flex-grow-1">Form</h1>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
            <h1 class="h-04 flex-grow-1">Awards</h1>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm so stupid, completely overlooked the input tags and didn't wrap everything in one form.